# Calculating time difference between two dates in java with consideration to business hours, work suspensions and weekends

Tags: java, validation, date, datetime, logic

I need to get the `MinutesRendered` on a specific `job` on my program. I have the `startdate` and `enddate` of that particular `job`. I need to count the difference between these 2 dates while skipping the holidays, weekends and only counting 8am-5pm per working days (Mon-Fri).

I find it hard to come-up with a logic that will do this. Is there any existing logic or snippet (not really have to be JAVA) that will show me how can this be possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903919/calculate-only-working-hours-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138449/calculate-number-of-hours-between-two-dates-not-including-weekends

Comment: All found by copying the title of your question to Google. Try that first

Answer (score 1):

A sample program could be for the logic you are asking for is

```
public static void main(String[] args){

       LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.now(), endDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(15);

       //List<String> holidays = Arrays.asList([HOLIDAY_LIST]);
       long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
       int daysCount = 0;
       for(int i=0;i<days;i++) {
           if(!("SATURDAY".equals(startDate.plusDays(i).getDayOfWeek().toString()) || "SUNDAY".equals(startDate.plusDays(i).getDayOfWeek().toString()))) {
               daysCount++;
           }
       }

       long minusMinutes = daysCount * 900;
       System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(startDate, endDate) - minusMinutes);      

    }
```

In the above code, `[HOLIDAY_LIST]` depends on you as you have to mention in List as I specified in the commented code.